# Confused with object initialization/instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the following class definition

```
 class Workflow
    # class << self; attr_acessor :id, :name, :url  end
    # Please ignore the troubleshooting attemp above it didn't help, I got the ObjectNil

    def self.initialize ( id, name, url )
      @id = id
      @name = name
      @url = url
    end

    # @return [Object]
    def  self.list
      ret = Array.new
      wf = Hash.new
      vco = Vco.new
      vco.getAll.each do |link|
        link['attributes'].each do |attr|
          wf[ attr['name'] ] = attr[ 'value' ]
        end
        ret.push( self.new( wf[ 'id' ], wf[ 'name' ], wf[ 'itemHref' ]  ) )
      end
      return   ret
    end
```

used as:

```
  <% @workflows.each do |wf| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= wf.id %></td>
        <td><%= wf.name %></td>
        <td><%= wf.url %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Thus the method `Workflow.list` should return an array of workflows. However, it doesn't do so as expected. When I use

```
        ret.push( self.new( wf[ 'id' ], wf[ 'name' ], wf[ 'itemHref' ]  ) )
```

I'm getting the "wrong number of arguments(3 for 0)" error. But when I use instead

```
       ret.push( self.initialize( wf[ 'id' ], wf[ 'name' ], wf[ 'itemHref' ]  ) )
```

the method `list` returns a list of url strings (it is the last assignment in the method, and should be that) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `initialise`? Show the definition of it.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, "initialiSe" was a typo made during the post preparation. In real code there was initialiZe.

Answer (score 1):

to remove that error on `self.new` call, change the `def self.initialize ( id, name, url )` to `def initialize ( id, name, url )`. `self.new` tries to create a `Workflow` instance,by calling default `initialize` method, which don't take any arguments,but you are providing it arguments,which in turn throws error.

Comment: Just tested it "def initialize ( id, name, url )" and "ret.push( self.new( wf[ 'id' ], wf[ 'name' ], wf[ 'itemHref' ]  ) )" now getting error "undefined method `id' for #<Workflow:0x4006e90>"

Comment: @Vsevolod   use as wf[@id]

Comment: :( "undefined method `[]' for #<Workflow:0x4573a58>  -- but in my understanding instance variables in Ruby are the same as objct properties in other languages, or I#m speaking nonsense?

Comment: ue `attr_acessor :id, :name, :url` in the class.

Comment: @Priti : `self.new tries to create a Workflow instance,by calling default initialize method, which don't take any arguments,but you are providing it arguments,which in turn throws error.` - self.new will call the initialize method which is accepting 3 arguments.

Comment: I did it already, and got the error message "unknown method attr_acessor" however I will try i again. Just to mention - " <td><%= wf.instance_variables %></td> " produces "[:@id, :@name, :@url]" will test wf[:@id]

Comment: @Anand very confused, what you are talking about.

Comment: @Anand, sorry, which self.new ? You mentioned in your answer self.new twice "self.new tries to create a Workflow instance" and "self.new will call the initialize method" ....

Comment: @Priti : `def initialize` is a constructor that automatically gets called when an instance is created by calling `Class.new`, the constructor in OP's code is accepting 3 arguments, you seem to be contradicting that by saying `...which don't take any arguments,but you are providing it arguments...`

Comment: @Anand No *you misread it*; read it carefully. What I meant is very true.

Answer (score 0):

First you've got `def self.initialize` which should be changed to `def initialize` since its a constructor. Constructor is a method that gets called when you do `Class.new` since you've defined the constructor as a class method you are getting the error.

Second the constructor is called `initialize` and you are making a call to `initialise` (typo?) if not fix that part as well.

Comment: Sorry, "initialiSe" was a typo made during the post preparation. In real code there was initialiZe